# How to call the program with single command in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, installation, bin, deno

My question may be wrong as I am completely don't know the exact way to define. What I am trying to figure it out is I have one program which is /home//.deno/bin/deno when I run this it executes the program but I want to create the shortcut way just by typing deno .
Please suggest me the correct name of this process

### Thanks

Currently when I type 
/home//.deno/bin/deno It open the program
but I want to make it just by typing 
deno
I am using Linux

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem. You should try asking it on Superuser or a Linux-related stack.

Comment: Click where it says "delete"

Answer (score 1):

In Linux when you type a command and it runs, it can be either a inbuilt command of shell or bash looks for a binary in paths defined by `$PATH` variable.

If you type `env` in your shell, you will see environment variables. Look at `PATH` variable. It has paths separated by `:` (a colon). Linux looks for your typed named binary file in those paths.

So you have two options:

1. Copy `/home//.deno/bin/deno` into your `/usr/local/bin`, `/bin`, or `/sbin` directory, or
2. Add `/home//.deno/bin/deno` path into your `PATH` variable.

[Read move info about updating your `PATH` variable](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `/home/.deno/bin` to your `PATH` variable.

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/home/.deno/bin
```

You can set it globally editing `/etc/profile` or set it for your specific user editing `.bashrc` (assuming your configured shell is `bash`)

Answer (score -1):

You can create Symlink in /usr/local/bin that references to full path of the application.

```
ln -s source_file symbolic_link
```

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/